# How to print Highest level parent nodes next to each of their child and grandchild nodes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, vba, algorithm

I have a PHP code which enables me to create an array of Parent nodes mapped with child nodes and grand child nodes. Here is the code that i used:

```
<?php
function parent_map( &$a, $parent_key, $children_key )
{
    $orphans = true; $i;
    while( $orphans )
    {
        $orphans = false;
        foreach( $a as $k=>$v )
        {
            // is there $a[$k] sons?
            $sons = false;
            foreach( $a as $x=>$y )
            if( isset($y[$parent_key]) and $y[$parent_key]!=false and $y[$parent_key]==$k )  
            { 
                $sons=true; 
                $orphans=true; 
                break;
            }

            // $a[$k] is a son, without children, so i can move it
            if( !$sons and isset($v[$parent_key]) and $v[$parent_key]!=false )
            {
                $a[$v[$parent_key]][$children_key][$k] = $v;
                unset( $a[$k] );
            }
        }
    }
}

$ARRAY = array(
    1 => array( 'label' => "A" ),
    2 => array( 'label' => "B" ),
    3 => array( 'label' => "C" ),
    4 => array( 'label' => "D" ),
    5 => array( 'label' => "one", 'father' => '1' ),
    6 => array( 'label' => "two", 'father' => '1' ),
    7 => array( 'label' => "three", 'father' => '1' ),
    8 => array( 'label' => "node 1", 'father' => '2' ),
    9 => array( 'label' => "node 2", 'father' => '2' ),
    10 => array( 'label' => "node 3", 'father' => '2' ),
    11 => array( 'label' => "I", 'father' => '9' ),
    12 => array( 'label' => "II", 'father' => '9' ),
    13 => array( 'label' => "III", 'father' => '9' ),
    14 => array( 'label' => "IV", 'father' => '9' ),
    15 => array( 'label' => "V", 'father' => '9' ),
);

parent_map( $ARRAY, 'father', 'children' );

echo "<pre>"; print_r( $ARRAY);


?>
```

This is able to give me a tree structure of the parent nodes and their child nodes and the child node's children and so on.

What i needed is data transformed from this form:

```
Parent Child

AAA   BBB
AAA   CCC
AAA   DDD
BBB   EEE
BBB   FFF
CCC   GGG
FFF   HHH
III   JJJ
JJJ   KKK
JJJ   LLL
```

to this form:

```
Node    1st Level Node
AAA     Root
BBB     AAA
CCC     AAA
DDD     AAA
EEE     AAA
FFF     AAA
GGG     AAA
HHH     AAA
III     Root
JJJ     III
KKK     III
LLL     III
```

in essence I wish to populate the child nodes with their respective highest level roots nodes such that all child nodes have a root level data/parent mapped to them.

I have tried using VBA in excel which works but hangs in large data sets. a solution to that is taking all data in at once and write out together but im not looking at a Macros solution.

here is my VBA code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main_Function_SuperManager()
Dim i, re
Root_Parent
Replace
Replace_Name
i = 1
    While Cells(i, 22) <> ""

         Cells(i, 22) = ""
         Cells(i, 23) = ""
         i = i + 1

    Wend
End Sub
Sub Root_Parent()
    Dim i, re, k
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Set re = Range("B:B").Find(Cells(i, 1))
        If re Is Nothing Then
            Set re = Range("V:V").Find(Cells(i, 1))
            If re Is Nothing Then
                k = k + 1
                Cells(k, 22) = Cells(i, 1)
                Cells(k, 23) = "Super Manager"
                findchild Cells(k, 22).Value, k
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
Sub findchild(parent, ByRef k)
 Dim i, s, re
 i = 1
    While Cells(i, 2) <> ""
    s = i
        Do
            Set re = Range("B:B").Find(Cells(s, 1))
            If re Is Nothing Then
                If Cells(s, 1) = parent Then
                k = k + 1
                Cells(k, 22) = Cells(i, 2)
                Cells(k, 23) = Cells(s, 1)
                End If
                Exit Do
            Else
                s = re.Row
            End If
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Sub Replace()
    Dim i, re, s
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, 22) <> ""
        Set re = Range("B:B").Find(Cells(i, 22))
        If re Is Nothing Then
        Cells(10, 24) = ""
        Else
         s = re.Row
         Cells(s, 19) = Cells(i, 23)
        End If
        i = i + 1

    Wend
End Sub

Sub Replace_Name()
    Dim i, re, s
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, 19) <> ""
        Set re = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(Cells(i, 19))
        If re Is Nothing Then
        Cells(10, 24) = ""
        Else
         s = re.Row
         Cells(i, 20) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(s, 2)
        End If
        i = i + 1

    Wend
End Sub
```

I'm hoping i can transform the same functionality into PHP. I shall populate the array from the DB but how to create a list of Unique ids/children to their highest level parent/ super parent node is something im unable to figure out.

Looking forward to advice on the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [`Disjoint-set`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure. Each node in this data structure holds a reference to its parent and each set will be represented by its `root` node. If you use this algorithm along with *path compression* improvement, the final parent array will be exactly what you want.

For this problem you should first initialize parent array like this:

```
parent[A] = A
parent[B] = B
...
```

then write the `find` function which recursively finds the root of each set and assigns that as the parent of the all the nodes in the path:

```
function find(x)
    if parent[x] == x: // x is root
        return x
    root = find(parent[x]) 
    parent[x] = root
```

Next step is to process the edges

```
for each U->V
    parent[V] = find(U) // finds the root of the tree that U belongs to
                        // and assign that as parent of V

A->B, find(A)=A, parent[B] <- A
A->C, find(A)=A, parent[C] <- A
A->D, find(A)=A, parent[D] <- A
B->E, find(B)=A, parent[E] <- A
B->F, find(B)=A, parent[F] <- A
C->G, find(C)=A, parent[G] <- A
F->H, find(C)=A, parent[F] <- H
I->J, find(I)=I, parent[J] <- I
J->K, find(J)=I, parent[K] <- J
J->L, find(J)=I, parent[L] <- J
```

Comment: I am unable to transform this into a PHP code since I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> Alter table it should be look like below

```
CREATE TABLE `parent_child` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> Create function for getting parent child element

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `yourdatabase`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetAllNode1`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetAllNode1`(GivenID INT) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children TEXT;
    DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;
    SET rv = '';
    SET queue = GivenID;
    SET queue_length = 1;
    WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
        SET front_id = queue;
        IF queue_length = 1 THEN
            SET queue = '';
        ELSE
            SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
            SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
            SET queue = q;
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;
        SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
        FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS qc
        FROM `parent_child` WHERE `parent_id` = front_id) A ;
        IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue_length = 0;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                SET rv = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN rv;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

write query for desire output

```
SELECT GetAllNode1(id) FROM parent_child 
or 
SELECT GetAllNode1(id) FROM parent_child  where id =1 //for specific parent's child element
```